# Any Mulesoft adaptar or connector available for Temenos Payment Suite TPH

Tags: mule, esb, mule-component, mule-el

Would like to know is there any Mulesoft connector/adaptar available for connecting Temenos Payment Suite.. like T24 Mulesoft connectors.. 
Require details on how to connect TPH to Mulesoft ESB. 
so could you please share the link / details. 
It will be helpful if you share the latest version of mulesoft adaptar details for Temenos Payment Suite TPH /TPS

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there aren't any connector available to connect Payment suite, however I hope you already know there is Mulesoft connector for inbound/outbound T24 events.

best option either speak to Mulesoft or Temenos people to get refined information. Temenos does not publish their documentation publicly so you have to rely on their response.

Here is the more details about what is available for Temenos on Mulesoft 
https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/68ef9520-24e9-4cf2-b2f5-620025690913/temenos-t24-connector/

Manoj Jangid